# Bluetooth is STILL disabled in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, failover

I tried everything, but bluetooth is still disabled.
I tried these:

1. sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3
2. sudo apt-get install gksu -y
   If you have GKSU (installed or already have) enter the following:
   gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
   The rc.local fill will open up, add the following line before the exit 0:
   rfkill unblock bluetooth

My laptop is fine (bluetooth worked well with older versions of ubi)
system is up to date, bluetooth is not blocked.

Rebooted, but still nothing...
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
sudo mv /etc/bluetooth /etc/bluetooth.backup

sudo apt-get install --reinstall bluez
```

After a reboot check the issue. The /etc/bluetooth directory should be empty now.

If this does not work for you, just move back the bluetoth.backup directory to it's original place.

**(or)**

Missing Firm-ware could also be an issue and you can fix it with the command

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Hope this helps!